# Prove that perpendiculars from midpoints of orthic triangle to opposite sides are concurrent.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are the altitudes of $\triangle ABC$. If $P$, $Q$, $R$ are the mid-points of $DE$, $EF$, $FD$, respectively, then show that the perpendicular from $P$, $Q$, $R$ to $AB$, $BC$, $CA$, respectively, are concurrent.

[image]

I first thought of Carnot's theorem, but I don't see anything about the lengths required.
So, I looked at $\triangle DEF$, I know $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ are angle bisectors of the orthic triangle. Therefore, the problem reduces to proving, lines parallel to angle bisectors, passing through midpoints of the respective sides are concurrent.

To solve this, I thought of using a phantom point. Let lines through $Q$ and $R$, parallel to $AD$ and $BE$ respectively intersect at $M$, let line through $M$, parallel to $CF$ intersect $DE$ at $P'$, it is to be proved that $P'$ is the midpoint of $DE$.
[image]

I tried some basic angle chasing but could not proceed further than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceeding from your first idea, let's consider the labeled figure below and $\triangle P'RQ$.

[image]

It is very easy to note that:

$$\angle D_1=\angle D_2=\angle Q_1, \\ \angle D_1=\angle Q_2.$$

Therefore, $QN$ is the angle bisector of $\angle RQP'$, and we are done because $M$ must be the incenter of $\triangle P'RQ$.

Comment: You can find all the formulae you need in Maxwell's old book on homogeneous coordinates in plane projective geometry.

Comment: How did you prove $\angle D_1 = \angle Q_2$. Also how does $M$ being the incenter prove that $P'$ is midpoint of $DE$?

Comment: @Frosty For the first part, note that the angles are formed by $DP'$ and $DX$ and $QR$ and $NQ$, and $DX||QN$ and $DP' ||PQ$. For the second part, we already assumed that $P'$ is the midpoint. We just proved $QN$ is the angle bisector. The same goes for the other two parallel lines. Finally, we use the fact that the angle bisectors of a triangle are concurrent at the incenter.

Comment: @Frosty I forgot to say that I used your figure simply as a figure, assuming that $P'$, $Q$, and $R$ are the midpoints. The main idea was to use the fact that the angle bisectors are concurrent. That's why we needed to show that $QN$ was the angle bisector.